# Angular Architecture: Passing Data to Child from Parent

Tags: angular

In the following example of templates within a template...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-a',
  template: 
    `<div>
       <component-b></component-b>
     </div>`
})
```

Is it best practice to have `component-b` share a service with `component-a` from which `component-a` gets `component-b`'s properties and passes them to `component-b` with `@Input()`?

Or...

Is it preferable for `component-b` to have its own service and to not rely on its parent for data?

I've picked up a project after a year of being away from it. In some ways it's more difficult to approach this monster half finished than it was to start from nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the relationship between the components is parent-child, a service will most likely be overkill for what you have to accomplish.

Use `@Input()` and `@Output()` to pass data between the two, you can have a look at the [official tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3), where the Angular team covered this topic in detail.

Comment: Are you saying a service dedicated to the child is overkill?

Comment: If the only purpose of the service is to pass data from parent to child, yes it is

Comment: A different scenario would be if the data you pass from the parent is required by other components as well, which might not be in a direct relationship with the parent. In that case, a service would probably be a good idea

Comment: Yeah, the parent gets its own data from an existing service of its own. Currently, the child has its own service. This seems contrived to me. So you're saying that it would be best to use the parent's existing service to get the child's data?

Comment: Yes its advised that the child component is not tightly coupled with the parent .

Comment: Yes. Angular is smart enough to handle all the events between service-parent-child and update the models for you